# Can we Load TDL file to Tally through C# code automatically

Tags: c#, tally

I Am having an tool which is developed in *`C#`* to fetch data from *`Tally`* to my local database.

As of now I am manually loading the TDL file in Tally and then fetching data from C#.

**But is there any way to load TDL file automatically to Tally through my C# code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we cant automatically load the TDL file by 3rd party software.

Comment: Thats not true, I am still sending TDL through XML and its working

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: I already added answer, you can refer that

Answer (score 1):

If you have Tally Developer license you can convert TDL to XML and send to Tally

[image]

If you don't, then you need to manually convert TDL to XML, which is pretty much time-consuming

Example [XML](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt#1f208a14-b20c-4bea-853c-3964e189587a) for custom group report where TDL is send in XML

**Note :** [This custom TDL reports](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt#88feee31-b22a-4baa-b5e3-014d5cbc60ff) are generated through [TallyConnector`s](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector) upcoming feature which converts C# objects to TDL in XML which is not fully tested yet